# awk + how to count words in the first field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file as the following file on rhel 7.2 machine

```
more file.txt


car12
car55
car87
car12
car98
car55
car12
car12
car55
car65
car12
car65
```

we want to sum the words in the file with the quantity as the follwing expected results

```
car12 - 5
car55 - 3
car87 - 1
car98 - 1
car65 - 2
```

how to sum the above words with their quantity with awk ?

Comment: Maybe using associative arrays?

Comment: why with `awk` ? you can do with `sort` and `uniq`. `sort file.txt | uniq -c` should do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need awk for this, you can simply do:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      5 car12
      3 car55
      2 car65
      1 car87
      1 car98
```

But yes, it is possible in awk also:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(word in a){print word" - "a[word]}}' file 
car55 - 3
car65 - 2
car87 - 1
car12 - 5
car98 - 1
```

---

With **GNU awk** (`gawk`), one may even use a few [predefined sortings](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) regarding how the array is traversed, and by extension how it is printed. If you use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"`, that will cause the results to be printed in the order from most seen to least:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++} 
       END { 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";
        for(word in a){print word" - "a[word]}
       }' file
car12 - 5
car55 - 3
car65 - 2
car87 - 1
car98 - 1
```